# How can I verify an alter column data type change with sqitch postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, postgresql-10, sqitch

I am making the following `deploy` change. Changing the value of a `timestamp` column to `timestamptz`.

```
-- Alter the is_deleted flags to be timestamp with time zone
alter table source_meta.sources alter column is_deleted set data type timestamptz
      using
        is_deleted at time zone 'UTC';
alter table source_meta.series alter column is_deleted set data type timestamptz
      using
        is_deleted at time zone 'UTC';
```

How can I write a `verify` script that will error if the data type has not been changed?

Also need some help with `revert` to drop timezone from a timestamptz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks pretty good to me, @nackjicholson. If you wanted a more informative error message, you could wrap it in a `DO` block and raise an error:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM TRUE
       FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_name  = 'sources'
        AND column_name = 'is_deleted'
        AND data_type   = 'timestamp with time zone';
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'sources.is_deleted type is not timestamptz';
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help David!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1/count(*)
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'sources'
 and column_name = 'is_deleted'
 and data_type = 'timestamp with time zone';
```

That's what I can come up with, but not being an expert I'm not sure if that's the way to do it or just stupid. :)

This throws a division by zero error if no rows found with that criteria.